# Space complexity bounds of a recursion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, space-complexity

So I have a seam Carving function:

```
int seamCarve(int i, int j, int width)
{
   if(j < 0 || j >= width) //width is just a constant
      return INT_MAX;
   if (i == 0)
      return e(i,j);  //just some int value in this case

   int best = INT_MAX;
   for(int k = -1; k <=1; k++)
     best = min(best, seamCarve(i - 1, (j+k) % width),width));

   return best + e(i,j);
}
```

I m having trouble visualizing the space complexity of this function.
space complexity is number of extra variables (space) needed for the algorithm as far as I know. In this case it's `int best`.

Here's my analysis: when i == 0, space complexity would be O(1) because it doesn't even create an extra variable. So that would be lower bound.
For the upper bound it would be O(i^3) because there's a for loop that iterate 3 times. Inside the for loop it also calls seamCarve i times. So the maximum times `best` gets changed would be i^3 times.

Is there a problem with my analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks like it will be O(3^n). The calls arguments would look something like:

```
level1: (i, 0)
level2: (i-1, -1), (i-1, 0), (i-1, 1)
level3: (i-2, -2), (i-2, -1), (i-2, 0), (i-2, -1), (i-2, 0), (i-2, 1),(i-2, 0), (i-2, 1), (i-2, 2)
```

If already calculated seamCarve() results are stored and reused it will be only O(i* width). Let's say `S` is starting `(i, j)` and X is points that need to be calculated:

```
0-----width 

XXXXXXXXXXX  0
XXXXXXXXXXX  |
XXXXXXXXXXX  |
XXXXXXXXXXX  |
XX..XXXXXXX  |
X....XXXXXX  |
......XXXXX  |
.......XXX.  |
........S..  i
```